# Iteratively removing list elements in Python - list comprehension vs for loop, different results

Tags: python-2.7

Given an edge set (a list of lists in python speak) of a hypergraph (e.g. l = [[1,2,3], [2], [3], [3,4]]), the task is to remove all edges which contain a specific vertex (e.g. vertex 2).
For above example, the result should be [[3], [3, 4]].

I have troubles to understand why the first function does not work as expected.

```
def edge_delete(edge_set, v0):
    """ delete all edges containing vertex v0 """
    for edge in edge_set:
        if v0 in edge:
            edge_set.remove(edge)
    return edge_set
```

gives

```
l = [[1,2,3], [2], [3], [3,4]]
edge_delte(l, 2)
[[2], [3], [3, 4]]
```

It is not clear to me why element [1,2,3] was removed, but not element [2].

The below gives the correct result

```
def edge_delete_v2(edge_set, v0):
    """ delete all edges containing vertex v0 """
    return [edge for edge in edge_set if v0 not in edge]
```

gives

```
l = [[1,2,3], [2], [3], [3,4]]
edge_delete_v2(l, 2)
[[3], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: The first doesn't work because you're removing items from the list you're iterating over. when you remove the first element [1,2,3], the list changes length. When you check the 'second element' it looks at index 1 which is now the element [3]. the element [2] is never checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code is trying to modify a list as you are iterating through it, which can trip up the iteration.

The second is not modifying the list at all; it is using it to build up a brand new list with the elements that would not get deleted.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!